# How to get Firestore DocumentReference Class?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I want to obtain the Firestore DocumentReference Class to compare, if X is a instance of DocumentReference.
According to the firebase-admin-node changelog (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/e6d6c5e0920c4a914ed564c04fae3311899986d6/CHANGELOG.md) in version 5.8.2, it is possible.

```
//SDK_VERSION: '5.8.2'
import admin from 'firebase-admin'
console.log(admin.firestore.DocumentReference);
```

but it does not happen, return undefined. Any idea that may be happening? Thanks

Update:
I made a new clean project, the problem still persists

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const fs = require('fs');
const credentialsBuffer = fs.readFileSync('/Users/pablo/Downloads/cred.json');
const credentials = JSON.parse(credentialsBuffer.toString());
const appName = 'test';

const adminApp = admin.initializeApp(
  { credential: admin.credential.cert(credentials) },
  appName
);

let app = admin.app(appName);
console.log('here!', admin.firestore.DocumentReference); // return undefined
```

And the package.json

```
{
  "name": "A test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": " node index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^5.8.2"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Comment: Where are you initializing the Admin SDK?

Comment: Also, can you show your package.json to verify the version of Admin?

Comment: @JenPerson thanks for the quick response, I updated the question with a new project, to answer what you ask me

Comment: To me, this looks like a bug in the underlying @google-cloud/firestore SDK, which is manifesting itself via the Admin SDK exports.  I've filed a bug internally at Google, feel free to report another one via Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: Are you on TypeScript or plain Node.js? It seems the types are available when coding with TypeScript.

Comment: I'm on plain node.js

Comment: Interesting, thanks.

I have been looking at the file [https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/0e5198e330be7dc9253f5944690ad5a113fb1151/src/index.d.ts](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/0e5198e330be7dc9253f5944690ad5a113fb1151/src/index.d.ts)

and I think to get the type we should be capable to get the type like this


`const Firestore = require ('@google-cloud/firestore');`

`console.log (Firestore.DocumentReference);`


but not

Comment: Yes, it seems the types are not available at JS runtime. Only at TS compile time. Firestore SDK team is looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed with https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/pull/123 and will be part of the next @google-cloud/firestore release.

If you are blocked on this, you can pull in the NPM package from head as outlined here: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#github-urls

Comment: @google-cloud/firestore v0.12.0 includes a fix for this issue.